# scrlayer-scrpage: Have headsepline intersect, but not strike through, text

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I would like to have the header text be intersected by the headsepline. To this end, I though I could put the header text in a colorbox (normally white, I made it gray in the MWE to make it visible) and move it down. This works; however, the headsepline is on the "layer" above the header text and therefore strikes through the text. How can I put the colorbox "on top of" (layer-wise) the headsepline? Or do I need to use a completely different approach? If so, how would I do this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,headsepline,chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xcolor}

%%%---header/footer
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

%%--"Chapter #" in lehead (only for numbered chapters), chapter name in rohead
\renewcommand*
\chaptermark[1]{%
    \markboth{\ifnumbered{chapter}{\vspace{-14pt} \colorbox{gray!20}{\chaptermarkformat}}{}}{\vspace{-14pt} \colorbox{gray!20}{#1}\hspace{4pt}}%
    }

\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\markboth{}{\contentsname}}

\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{empty} 


\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\lipsum[1-20]

\chapter{Second}

\lipsum[21-40]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I didn't misunderstand you, `\vspace{0pt}` is not sufficient for this?

Comment: @ferahfeza As you can see in the image, I have the text exactly where I want it in regard to its vertical and horizontal position. But the headsepline strikes through the text, which I do not want. I am looking for a way to have the headsepline "behind" the colorbox in which the text is. I have updated the image to better show what I accomplished vs. what I actually want.

Comment: Ok, now it is more clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is the order of the layers in the layer page style. You can list all layers of a layer page style using:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\newcommand*\commaatlist{}
\newcommand*\listpagestylelayers[1]{
  \ForEachLayerOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{%
    \commaatlist##1\gdef\commaatlist{, }}
  \let\commaatlist\relax
}
\begin{document}
\raggedright
\listpagestylelayers{scrheadings}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can remove layer `scrheadings.head.below.line` and add this layer before the other layers:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\newcommand*\commaatlist{}
\newcommand*\listpagestylelayers[1]{
  \ForEachLayerOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{%
    \commaatlist##1\gdef\commaatlist{, }}
  \let\commaatlist\relax
}

% reorder the layers -> headsepline behind header text
\RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{scrheadings}{scrheadings.head.below.line}
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{scrheadings.head.below.line}

\begin{document}
\raggedright
\listpagestylelayers{scrheadings}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Then you can use

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,headsepline,chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}
%\providecommand*\Ifstr{\ifstr}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
%\providecommand*\Ifnumbered{\ifnumbered}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% reorder the layers -> headsepline behind header text
\RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{scrheadings}{scrheadings.head.below.line}
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{scrheadings.head.below.line}

%%--"Chapter #" in lehead (only for numbered chapters), chapter name in rohead
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\Ifnumbered{chapter}{\chaptermarkformat}{}}{#1}}
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\markboth{}{\contentsname}}

\lehead{\Ifstr{\leftmark}{}{}{%
  ~\raisebox{-.75\ht\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{\colorbox{gray!20}{\strut\leftmark}}%
}}
\rohead{\Ifstr{\rightmark}{}{}{%
  \raisebox{-.75\ht\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{\colorbox{gray!20}{\strut\rightmark}}~%
}}
%\ofoot*{\pagemark}% default

\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\minisec{Dummy text to get more ToC pages:}
\lipsum[41-50]

\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1-20]
\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[21-40]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Additional suggestion using a rule in header without `headsepline`:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,chapterprefix=true,headheight=20pt]{scrreprt}
%\providecommand*\Ifstr{\ifstr}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
%\providecommand*\Ifnumbered{\ifnumbered}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

%%--"Chapter #" in lehead (only for numbered chapters), chapter name in rohead
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\Ifnumbered{chapter}{\chaptermarkformat}{}}{#1}}
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\markboth{}{\contentsname}}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\lehead{\rule[.75\dp\strutbox]{\linewidth}{.4pt}}
\lohead{\rule[.75\dp\strutbox]{\linewidth}{.4pt}}
\cehead{~\Ifstr{\leftmark}{}{}{\colorbox{gray!20}{\strut\leftmark}}\hfill}
\cohead{\hfill\Ifstr{\rightmark}{}{}{\colorbox{gray!20}{\strut\rightmark}}~}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% short version of \ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
Dummy text to get more ToC pages:
\lipsum[41-50]

\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1-20]
\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[21-40]
\end{document}
```

### [image]

Comment: Thank you for also cleaning up my very clumsy attempt at adding and positioning the colorbox.