# scrlayer-scrpage: switch layers of pagestyle when defining \newpairofpagestyles

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

From an earlier question ([scrlayer-scrpage: Have headsepline intersect, but not strike through, text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527079/scrlayer-scrpage-have-headsepline-intersect-but-not-strike-through-text)), I got the code included in the MWE on how to switch layers in page styles of scrlayer-scrpage. However, when I define a new pair of page styles, the layer switching is undone. How do I switch the layers again? (the MWE includes one of my attempts, doing the switch right after `\clearscrheadfoot`)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,headsepline,twoside,chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{xcolor}

%%%---header/footer
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% reorder the layers -> headsepline behind header text
\RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{scrheadings}{scrheadings.head.below.line}
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{scrheadings.head.below.line}

%%--"Chapter #" in lehead (only for numbered chapters), chapter name in rohead
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\Ifnumbered{chapter}{\chaptermarkformat}{}}{#1}}
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\markboth{}{\contentsname}}

\lehead{\Ifstr{\leftmark}{}{}{%
        ~\raisebox{-.75\ht\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{\colorbox{gray!20}{\strut\leftmark}}%
}}
\rohead{\Ifstr{\rightmark}{}{}{%
        \raisebox{-.75\ht\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{\colorbox{gray!20}{\strut\rightmark}}~%
}}

\newpairofpagestyles{MyAppend}{%
    \clearscrheadfoot%
    \RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{scrheadings}{scrheadings.head.below.line}
    \AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{scrheadings.head.below.line}
    \ohead*{\Ifstr{\headmark}{}{}{%
            \raisebox{-.75\ht\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{\colorbox{green!20}{\strut Custom Text}}~%
    }}
    \ofoot*{\pagemark} 
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\lipsum[1-14]

\newpage

\pagestyle{MyAppend}

\lipsum[41-50]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you really need both styles MyAppend and plain.MyAppend? This new plain style should take the »Custom Text« entry, too?

Comment: @esdd Yes, I need it for the "Custom Text" entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to switch the layers for style `MyAppend` you have to use the name of this style and the layers of this style:

```latex
\RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{MyAppend}{MyAppend.head.below.line}
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{MyAppend}{MyAppend.head.below.line}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,headsepline,twoside,chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%%%---header/footer
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% reorder the layers -> headsepline behind header text
\RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{scrheadings}{scrheadings.head.below.line}
\AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{scrheadings.head.below.line}

%%--"Chapter #" in lehead (only for numbered chapters), chapter name in rohead
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\Ifnumbered{chapter}{\chaptermarkformat}{}}{#1}}
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\markboth{}{\contentsname}}

\ohead{\Ifstr{\headmark}{}{}{%
  \ifodd\value{page}\else~\fi
  \raisebox{-.75\ht\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{\colorbox{gray!20}{\strut\headmark}}%
  \ifodd\value{page}~\fi
}}% changed


\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{MyAppend}{%
  \clearpairofpagestyles% <- changed
  \RemoveLayersFromPageStyle{MyAppend}{MyAppend.head.below.line}% <- changed!
  \AddLayersAtBeginOfPageStyle{MyAppend}{MyAppend.head.below.line}% <- changed!
  \ohead*{%
    \ifodd\value{page}\else~\fi
    \raisebox{-.75\ht\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{\colorbox{green!20}{\strut Custom Text}}%
    \ifodd\value{page}~\fi
  }% changed
  \ofoot*{\pagemark}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1-14]
\newpage
\pagestyle{MyAppend}
\lipsum[41-50]
\end{document}
```

[image]